# Can I use different Schemes in different versions of Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I wanna use different schemes for different versions of Visual Studio so that I have some quick visual way for me to determine which IDE I'm in. I like how Visual Studio is tied to my Microsoft account but that makes it problematic for this. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Heres how i solved the problem: Installed VS2017. When starting the IDE for the first time i DIDNT sign in with my microsoft account. I went to Tools => Options => and turned off synching settings. THEN I signed in with my microsoft account.